# How to know what optimizations are enabled by clang and gcc for each mcpu and march option?

Tags: gcc, optimization, clang

Clang and GCC have two switches, `-mcpu` and `-march`, to enable some optimizations especific for the CPU selected. i.e. `-march=i686` enables internally `-mmmx`, `-msse` and so forth.

I would like know if there is some command to show what switches are enabled by `march` and `mcpu` for each CPU. I prefer just a command but I also accept answers with the location of the code with the info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For gcc, try

`gcc -mcpu=native -Q --help=target`

The first line it prints:

> gcc: warning: ‘-mcpu=’ is deprecated; use ‘-mtune=’ or ‘-march=’
>   instead

followed by

```
The following options are target specific:
  -m128bit-long-double                  [disabled]
  -m32                                  [disabled]
  -m3dnow                               [disabled]
  -m3dnowa                              [disabled]
  -m64                                  [enabled]
  -m80387                               [enabled]
  -m8bit-idiv                           [disabled]
   [...]
```

**That answers the part for gcc.**

---

Unfortunately, I am not familiar with clang. The best I could figure out so far is:

`clang --target=i386 -###  myfile.c`.

where the `-###` makes the options to be shown. Different things are shown for arm. I am not sure if it is sufficient for you.

The file that sets the options seems to be [Targets.cpp](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/Targets_8cpp_source.html), although it is not much help as it a 5.8k line long file.

After looking at the llvm code generation, **I have the impression that clang/LLVM doesn't have so many target specific options as gcc.** See for example [the target-specific feature matrix](http://llvm.org/docs/CodeGenerator.html#target-specific-implementation-notes) or the exposed (documented) [options of llc](http://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llc.html).

And one more thing: clang exposes far less options of the compiler optimizations on purpose. For example there is [no `-finline-limit` analogue exposed in clang.](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.compilers.llvm.devel/38186)

Maybe `-###` prints everything exposed after all.

Comment: A bit offtopic, but: clang has the inlining control option. `-mllvm -inline-threshold=...`. There is quite a number of options available via `clang -mllvm -help-hidden`. Although, I won't state that clang exposes as much options as GCC does — I just don't know.

Answer (score 3):

As already stated, `gcc -Q --help=target` prints information about optimizations in human-readable form.

clang doesn't seem to have a specific option for that. But you can retrieve some information if you compile simple program into LLVM IR.

Example command:

`echo 'int main(){}' | clang -S -emit-llvm -x c - -o - | grep attributes`.

Example output:

```
attributes #0 = { noinline nounwind optnone uwtable "correctly-rounded-divide-sqrt-fp-math"="false" "disable-tail-calls"="false" "frame-pointer"="all" "less-precise-fpmad"="false" "min-legal-vector-width"="0" "no-infs-fp-math"="false" "no-jump-tables"="false" "no-nans-fp-math"="false" "no-signed-zeros-fp-math"="false" "no-trapping-math"="false" "stack-protector-buffer-size"="8" "target-cpu"="x86-64" "target-features"="+cx8,+fxsr,+mmx,+sse,+sse2,+x87" "unsafe-fp-math"="false" "use-soft-float"="false" }
```

Tested on clang-10.